# Generate SSL Certificates Failed - Installation Error

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I am trying to install IBM Cloud Private CE 2.1.0.3 on my local machine (single node) and I encounter following error during the installation process (verbose mode with -vvv is on):

```
TASK [certificates : Generating ssl certificates] ******************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/certificates/tasks/certificate.yaml:27
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d15 ssh -C -o CheckHostIP=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/installer/cluster/ssh_key"' -o User=user -o ConnectTimeout=60 -oPubkeyAuthentication=no 127.0.0.1 '/bin/bash -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> (0, '/home/user\n', '')
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d15 ssh -C -o CheckHostIP=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/installer/cluster/ssh_key"' -o User=user -o ConnectTimeout=60 -oPubkeyAuthentication=no 127.0.0.1 '/bin/bash -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624="` echo /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624=/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624\n', '')
<127.0.0.1> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-14gnUpht/tmp_VvSJv TO /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624/command.py
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d15 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o CheckHostIP=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/installer/cluster/ssh_key"' -o User=user -o ConnectTimeout=60 -oPubkeyAuthentication=no '[127.0.0.1]'
<127.0.0.1> (0, 'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-14gnUpht/tmp_VvSJv /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624/command.py\n', '')
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d15 ssh -C -o CheckHostIP=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/installer/cluster/ssh_key"' -o User=user -o ConnectTimeout=60 -oPubkeyAuthentication=no 127.0.0.1 '/bin/bash -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624/ /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624/command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> (0, '', '')
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d15 ssh -C -o CheckHostIP=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/installer/cluster/ssh_key"' -o User=user -o ConnectTimeout=60 -oPubkeyAuthentication=no -tt 127.0.0.1 '/bin/bash -c '"'"'sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=iwoajxmkcbeqtvsibemwhzxoiowwbdgi] password: " -u root /bin/bash -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-iwoajxmkcbeqtvsibemwhzxoiowwbdgi; /usr/bin/python /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624/command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<127.0.0.1> (1, '\r\n\r\n{"changed": true, "end": "2018-06-08 08:00:21.114115", "stdout": "", "cmd": "CERT_DIR=/installer/cluster/cfc-certs /installer/playbook/roles/certificates/files/kubernetes/make-ca-cert.sh 127.0.0.1 IP:127.0.0.1,IP:10.0.0.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,DNS:mycluster.icp", "failed": true, "delta": "0:00:00.003196", "stderr": "/bin/bash: /installer/playbook/roles/certificates/files/kubernetes/make-ca-cert.sh: No such file or directory", "rc": 127, "invocation": {"module_args": {"warn": true, "executable": "/bin/bash", "_uses_shell": true, "_raw_params": "CERT_DIR=/installer/cluster/cfc-certs /installer/playbook/roles/certificates/files/kubernetes/make-ca-cert.sh 127.0.0.1 IP:127.0.0.1,IP:10.0.0.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,DNS:mycluster.icp", "removes": null, "creates": "/installer/cluster/cfc-certs/server.key", "chdir": null, "stdin": null}}, "start": "2018-06-08 08:00:21.110919", "msg": "non-zero return code"}\r\n', 'Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n')
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d15 ssh -C -o CheckHostIP=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/installer/cluster/ssh_key"' -o User=user -o ConnectTimeout=60 -oPubkeyAuthentication=no 127.0.0.1 '/bin/bash -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528437619.25-45151919681624/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> (0, '', '')
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": "CERT_DIR=/installer/cluster/cfc-certs /installer/playbook/roles/certificates/files/kubernetes/make-ca-cert.sh 127.0.0.1 IP:127.0.0.1,IP:10.0.0.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,DNS:mycluster.icp", 
    "delta": "0:00:00.003196", 
    "end": "2018-06-08 08:00:21.114115", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "CERT_DIR=/installer/cluster/cfc-certs /installer/playbook/roles/certificates/files/kubernetes/make-ca-cert.sh 127.0.0.1 IP:127.0.0.1,IP:10.0.0.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,DNS:mycluster.icp", 
            "_uses_shell": true, 
            "chdir": null, 
            "creates": "/installer/cluster/cfc-certs/server.key", 
            "executable": "/bin/bash", 
            "removes": null, 
            "stdin": null, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "non-zero return code", 
    "rc": 127, 
    "start": "2018-06-08 08:00:21.110919", 
    "stderr": "/bin/bash: /installer/playbook/roles/certificates/files/kubernetes/make-ca-cert.sh: No such file or directory", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/bash: /installer/playbook/roles/certificates/files/kubernetes/make-ca-cert.sh: No such file or directory"
    ], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=44   changed=13   unreachable=0    failed=1   

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 2 minutes, 32 seconds

user@kim:/opt/ibm-cloud-private-ce-2.1.0.3/cluster$
```

It says "no such file or directory" for the "make-ca-cert.sh" file in the installer directory, but I don't quite know what I am supposed to do to fix this.

I am very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kim, could you let me check your ICP hosts and your /etc/hosts files? Normally, you can not specify '127.0.0.1' in ICP hosts file for installation, thanks.

Comment: I changed my ip from 127.0.0.1 to my ethernet ip address 192.168.240.14 and either this or the upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 fixed this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy your ssh key for the ansible user or root(which ever you are using) to the $install_dir/cluster/ssh_key file?

Example, mine is /opt/ibm-cloud-private-ce-2.1.0.3/cluster/ssh_key

Specifically, steps 6 and 8 in Step 2 here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0.3/installing/install_containers_CE.html#setup

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I followed these steps and the ssh connection works (before doing these steps, the installation would fail right away because of "Permission denied" or "connection refused" errors). I also changed from my user to root and did the same with ssh configuration there, but it still fails at the same point while trying to generate ssl certificates. I don't know why, but the necessary folder/file seems to be missing for me.